# How to print one entity from a table using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
             Open     High     Low   Close  Shifted_Close  Movements  Sign
Date                                                                   
2018-04-21  8875.1  9075.0  8629.3  8944.6         8875.0       69.6   Positive
2018-04-22  8939.7  9072.0  8760.5  8811.8         8944.6     -132.8   Negative
2018-04-23  8796.3  9032.1  8784.9  8954.1         8811.8      142.3   Positive
2018-04-24  8959.0  9749.0  8947.0  9661.7         8954.1      707.6   Positive
2018-04-25  9661.7  9750.0  8767.0  8974.5         9661.7     -687.2   Negative
```

This is the table I have got using panda. I am wondering how to do a simple if function for sign on the latest entry "2018-04-25 ".

It would be something like:

```
if btc_usd_price_kraken['Sign'] == 'Negative':
      print("Buy coins now")
```

But I only want just one entry.

Thanks

Comment: Do you always want the latest entry or the latest entry for "2018-04-25" day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access all the records with `Signin = 'negative'` with:

```
df.loc[df['Sign']=='Negative']
```

Output:

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Shifted_Close   Movements   Sign
Date                            
2018-04-22  8939.7  9072.0  8760.5  8811.8  8944.6  -132.8  Negative
2018-04-25  9661.7  9750.0  8767.0  8974.5  9661.7  -687.2  Negative
```

You can access the last record with the condition like below:

```
df.loc[df['Sign']=='Negative'].iloc[-1]
```

Output:

```
Open               9661.7
High                 9750
Low                  8767
Close              8974.5
Shifted_Close      9661.7
Movements          -687.2
Sign             Negative
Name: 2018-04-25, dtype: object
```

Use the `if` condition to check the last `Sign` value:

```
if df.iloc[-1]['Sign'] == 'Negative':
    print("processing")
    # block to process
```

Comment: The data I get changes daily for each new day. I don't think I'm understanding your answer. But I just want to check if something is Negative and output something based on the last entry for Sign

Comment: Then this solution works. It checks for the last sign in value and returns that. Based on this last entry, you can carry on the processing with its values.

Comment: But I don't get how I can do an IF statement to make an output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this if he dataframe is alway sorted such that the last value is the bottom record:

```
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Sign')]
```

Output:

```
'Negative'
```

If not, you can:

```
df.sort_index().iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Sign')]
```

Comment: Thanks this has been useful and I can do an if statement with it. Is iloc part of Pandas?

Comment: Yes, you can include this as an expression in an if statement.  Yes, [`iloc'](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc) is part of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe's name is `df`.

First, notice that you will get the latest date with:

```
df.index.max()
```

Just use this to get the corresponding value of `Sign` that way, using `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df.index.max(), 'Sign']
```

This returns the value of `Sign` for the date of `2018-04-25`, which is what you are looking for to proceed with the if condition:

```
if df.loc[df.index.max(), 'Sign'] == 'Negative':
    print("Buy coins now")
```